# Impala Open/Alive Sessions Monitoring

Tags: jdbc, cloudera, impala

I have been looking around on the current available documentation as well as in the following UIs:

- Cloudera Manager (Impala Tab)
- Impala StateStore Web UI
- Impala Catalog Server Web UI

For a place where I can see the current open sessions.

Any idea where I could find it? or an alternative method for monitoring the alive Impala connections?

Answer (score 2):

This is a significant weakness (at least of the version of CM we're using).  The only solution I have found so far is:

First:

- Cloudera Manager Home > Impala
- Click Queries

This will show you *all* queries that are executing, and that have been executed within the selected time window.  This detail is high-level, and we have found it often shows queries as "Executing" that long-since failed (this may have been fixed in a more recent version of CDH than the 5.2.6 we run).

In any case, this list will identify the nodes running `impalad` in the Coordinator field.  To get much greater detail, access node-by-node.  If the host running a query you were interested in was called `node12`, use

```
http://node12:25000/queries
```

and look for "In flight" queries at the top.

Comment: Thanks Tom, all my previous progresses with CDH 5.4.8 and impalad version 2.2.0 have covered exactly the same alternatives you have mentioned because of similar issues as: incomplete queries that never end, diagnostic of errors, or memory issues. My question is more about being able to go deeper from the connections management point of view in order to be able to see how these can be related to the issues.

Answer (score 0):

https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_webui.html

Sessions Page
By default, the sessions page of the debug web UI is at http://impala-server-hostname:25000/sessions (non-secure cluster) or https://impala-server-hostname:25000/sessions (secure cluster).

This page displays information about the sessions currently connected to this impalad instance. For example, sessions could include connections from the impala-shell command, JDBC or ODBC applications, or the Impala Query UI in the Hue web interface.